# How to calculate $\sum_{n \in P}\frac{1}{n^2}, P=\{n \in \mathbb{N}: \exists (a,b) \in\ \mathbb{N^+} \times \mathbb{N^+} \mbox{ with } a^2+b^2=n^2\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, pythagorean-triples

How I can evaluate
$$\sum_{n \in P}\frac{1}{n^2} \quad \quad P=\{n \in \mathbb{N^+}: \exists (a,b) \in\ \mathbb{N^+} \times \mathbb{N^+} \mbox{ with } a^2+b^2=n^2\}$$
It's clearly convergent. I thought about seeing the sum as a sum of complex numbers using $(a+ib)(a-ib)=a^2+b^2$.

Comment: Do you know for which $n$ you can write $n^2$ as the sum of two nonzero squares?

Comment: That's not quite correct, as we have e.g. $15^2 = 12^2 + 9^2$, but we can't write $15$ as the sum of two squares. That's fixable, but that characterisation isn't very useful for an efficient computation of the sum. I was thinking about a characterisation in terms of the prime factorisation of $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We just have to understand which numbers $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ are such that $n^2$ *cannot* be written as $a^2+b^2$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{N}^+$. If there is some prime $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ that divides $n$, such prime splits in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ (the ring of gaussian integers), hence $n^2$ can be represented for sure as $a^2+b^2$ with $a,b\neq 0$. If $n$ is even then $n^2\equiv 0\pmod{4}$, hence $n^2=a^2+b^2$ gives that both $a$ and $b$ are even and the problem boils down to representing $(n/2)^2$. At last we have that the only numbers whose square cannot be represented as $a^2+b^2$ with $a,b\neq 0$ are the ones whose prime factors lie in the set made by $2$ and the primes $\equiv 3\pmod{4}$. That gives:
$$ \sum_{n\in P}\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}-\!\!\!\!\prod_{p\in\{2,3,7,\ldots\}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)^{-1}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{4}{3}\cdot\!\!\!\prod_{p\equiv 3\!\!\pmod{4}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)^{-1}.\tag{1}$$
Now, let $\chi$ be the non-principal Dirichlet character $\!\!\pmod{4}$ and $L(s,\chi)$ the associated Dirichlet L-function. We have:
$$ L(2,\chi) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2} = \prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{\chi(p)}{p^2}\right)^{-1},\tag{2} $$
$$ L(4,\chi) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^4} = \prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{\chi(p)}{p^4}\right)^{-1},\tag{3} $$
$$ \frac{L(4,\chi)}{L(2,\chi)}=\prod_{p}\left(1+\frac{\chi(p)}{p^2}\right)^{-1}=\prod_{p\equiv 3\!\!\pmod{4}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)^{-1}\prod_{p\equiv 1\!\!\pmod{4}}\left(1+\frac{1}{p^2}\right)^{-1}\tag{4}$$
hence:

> $$ S= \sum_{n\in P}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{4\, L(4,\chi)}{3\, L(2,\chi)}\cdot\!\!\prod_{p\equiv 1\!\!\pmod{\!\! 4}}\!\!\left(1+\frac{1}{p^2}\right).\tag{5}$$

Comment: Another nice formula is $$\sum_{n \in P}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\frac{\pi^2}{6}}{\prod_{p\equiv 3\bmod 4}\left(1+\frac{1}{p^2}\right)}$$ meaning that each integer can be writen as the product of an element of $P$ and the product of distinct primes of $4\mathbb N+3$ (you can add that to the answer if I am not wrong )

Comment: @Elaqqad: that is not completely correct. Every element of $P$ can be factored in a unique way as an "indecomposable part" (i.e. a number that is $1$ or a product of elements from $\{2,3,7,11,\ldots\}$) times a number $>1$ whose prime factors lie in $\{5,13,17,\ldots\}$. That gives:

$$ S = \prod_{p\in\{2,3,7,\ldots\}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)^{-1}\cdot\left(-1+\prod_{p\equiv 1\pmod{4}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)^{-1}\right)$$ that is equivalent to my $(1)$ from which $(5)$ is deduced.

Comment: for me the starting point is "each integer $n\geq 1$ can be written as the product of an element of $ P$ and the product of distinct primes of $4\mathbb N+3$"  meaning that: $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb N}\frac{1}{n^2}=\sum_{n \in P}\frac{1}{n^2} \prod_{p\equiv 3\bmod 4}\left(1+\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$$

Comment: @Elaqqad: what about the integer $1$?

Comment: @Elaqqad: according to your definition, $2$ should included in the set of primes $\equiv 3\pmod{4}$. $2\not\in P$.

Comment: yes you're right it's a little bit tricky but I do think that there must be another expression using the other product $p\equiv 3 mod 4$ I'm working on it

Comment: Are you sure about the numerical value?

Comment: @user153012: not 100% sure, but I haven't spotted any fallacy in my answer. If you did, please notice me about it.

Comment: numerically 0.127.. is wrong.

Comment: @Agenog: Probably I miscomputed something. Anyway now there is an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let $S(x)$ denote the number of positive integers not exceeding $x$ which can be expressed as a sum of two squares. Then, as proved by Landau in 1908 the following limit holds.
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{\ln x}}{x} S(x) = K,
$$
where $K \approx 0.76422365358922$ is a constant. The convergence to the constant $K$, known as the [Landau–Ramanujan constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Landau-RamanujanConstant.html) is very slow. The first ten thousand digits of $K$ is [here](http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/constants/LandauRamanujan.txt).

The exact value of $K$ can be expressed as
$$
K = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \prod_{\substack{p \text{ prime } \\ \equiv \, 3 \pmod{4}}} \left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)^{-1/2},
$$
so we have that
$$
\prod_{\substack{p \text{ prime } \\ \equiv \, 3 \pmod{4}}} \left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right) = \frac{1}{2K^2}.
$$

From the excellent answer of @Jack D'Aurizio we know that
$$
S = \sum_{n\in P}\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{4}{3}\cdot \prod_{\substack{p \text{ prime } \\ \equiv \, 3 \pmod{4}}} \left(1-\frac{1}{p^2}\right)^{-1}. \\
$$

Using the exact value of $K$ we could express your sum in term of the Landau–Ramanujan constant.

> $$
> S = \sum_{n\in P}\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{8K^2}{3}.
> $$

Numerically

> $$
> \begin{align}
> S \approx 
> 0.08749995296754071824615285056063798739937787259940111394813\\
> 9987884926591232919611579752270225245544983905801979851301833\\
> 539947996701320476568130203602037004645936371\dots\phantom{0000000000000}
> \end{align}
> $$

Note that the numerical evaluation of the product for $K$ is hopeless in this form. You could find an other expression for $K$ [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Landau-RamanujanConstant.html) (eq. 11), which has much faster convergence.